# FOS create user manually returns null value

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony

I am trying to create a user manually. however I am getting following error. Basically it returns post values as null

An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO users (username, username_canonical, email, email_canonical, enabled, salt, password, last_login, locked, expired, expires_at, confirmation_token, password_requested_at, roles, credentials_expired, credentials_expire_at, name, surname, company) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, null, 1, "48vgaw6nv7y8kk48kwo4k8o4os44c4c", null, null, 0, 0, null, null, null, "a:0:{}", 0, null, null, null, null]:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'username' cannot be null

here is my code

```
 /**
 * @Route("/add-user", name="add-user")
 */
public function AddUserAction(request $request)

{
    $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');

    $name=$request->request->get("name");
    $surname=$request->request->get("surname");
    $comapany=$request->request->get("company");
    $username=$request->request->get("username");
    $password=$request->request->get("password");
    $email=$request->request->get("email");
    $tel=$request->request->get("tel");
    $mobile=$request->request->get("mobile");
    $role=$request->request->get("role");

    $user = $userManager->createUser();
    $user->setUsername($username);
    $user->setEmail($email);
    $user->setPlainPassword($password);
    $user->setRoles(array($role));
    $user->setEnabled(true);
    $userManager->updateUser($user);


    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('index'));

}
```

Comment: I found it. I typed form names wrong... Sorry to disturb you guys....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. I typed form names wrong... Sorry to disturb you guys....